# Element not found by identifier in Appium

Tags: android, appium

I am getting following error:

```
ValueError: Element locator 'identifier=id/edittext1' did not match any elements.
```

There is an element with id `edittext1` but it is not recognized!

Comment: Try the **xpath** for element locating

Comment: have you tried by using other locator like cssselector or xpath?

Comment: @sai i think your facing syntax issue, can you please post your code here, so that i can help you out

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the similar problem.

I used **xpath** for element locating.

For your reference below is the sample *xpath*

```
Input Text  xpath=/hierarchy[@rotation="0"]/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index="0"]/android.widget.LinearLayout[@index="0"]/android.widget.FrameLayout[@index="0"]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index="0"]/android.widget.EditText[@index="0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another locator, i use to have the same problem. But with CssSelector it's working fine.

Example for click into button :

```
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[ng-click^='actionname']"));
element1.click();
```

Comment: PS : The example is just to make you understand how cssSelector is working !

Comment: How is the CSS relevant to native mobile application?

Comment: I use it for hybrid application, i'm sorry i'm not sure if it is possible or not for native app.